# How to issue commands in Luasocket FTP

Tags: lua, luasocket

Good afternoon,

i'm currently writing on a Lua-script to upload a JCL to an IBM Mainframe (z/OS) via FTP.
Before uploading my JCL, i first have to issue the command `site filetype=jes` to connect to JESPLEX.
I'd greatly appreciate it if anyone could tell me how to execute commands via Luasocket FTP.
Thank you for your help!

Steffen

Answer (score 1):

There is [`command` command](https://github.com/diegonehab/luasocket/blob/master/src/ftp.lua#L267-L278) that I don't see [documented](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/ftp.html), but it takes the same parameters as `get` and `put` commands. Given the [examples in the package](https://github.com/diegonehab/luasocket/blob/master/test/ftptest.lua), something like this should work:

```
ftp.command({
  url = "ftp://luasocket:wrong@".. host,
  command = "site",
  argument = "filetype=jes",
})
```